# Pdf to txt from http request

Tags: python, shell, http, pdf, converters

I have a set of links to pdf files:

```
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/10852/9012/1/oppgave-2003-10-30.pdf
```

Some of them are restricted, meaning I won't be able to access the pdf file, while others will go directly to the pdf file itself, like the link above.

I'm currently using the requests package (python) to access the files, but there are far to many files for me to download, and I also don't want the files in pdf.

What I would like to do is go to each link, check if the link is a pdf file, download that file (if necessary), turn it into a txt file, and delete the original pdf file.

I have a shell script that is a very good pdf to txt converter, but is it possible to run a shell script from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kieran Bristow has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26276876/21945) part of your question about how to run an external program from Python.

The other part of your question is about selectively downloading documents by checking whether the resource is a PDF document. Unless the remote server offers alternate representations of their documents (e.g. a text version), you will need to download the documents. To avoid downloading non-PDF documents you can send an initial `HEAD` request and look at the reply headers to determine the `content-type` like this:

```
import os.path
import requests

session = requests.session()

for url in [
    'https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/10852/9012/1/oppgave-2003-10-30.pdf',
    'https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/10852abcd/90121023/1234/oppgave-2003-10-30.pdf']:
    try:
        resp = session.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        if resp.headers['content-type'] == 'application/pdf':
            resp = session.get(url)
            if resp.ok:
                with open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(resp.content)
                    print "Saved {} to file {}".format(url, os.path.basename(url))
            else:
                print 'GET request for URL {} failed with HTTP status "{} {}"'.format(url, resp.status_code, resp.reason)
    except requests.HTTPError as exc:
        print "HEAD failed for URL {} : {}".format(url, exc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and script. However, when I run the script I only get the 'HEAD failed for URL' exeption, even though the links are valid pdf files.

Comment: @ArashSaidi - odd, it works for me using that URL. I have noticed that the server is a little strange, e.g. `https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/10852/9012/1/oppgave-2003-10-30.txt` also returns a PDF. Are you using the same URL as in my answer?

Comment: The first link I used is: https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/10852/9012/1/oppgave-2003-10-30.pdf

Comment: But I have a 26546 links, and all of them return the error message.

Comment: What is the full error message including the value of exc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It is entirely possible to run shell scripts from python. Take a look at the subprocess python module which allows you to create processes kind of how you would with a shell: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

For example:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "message"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print process.communicate()
```

There are many tutorials out there e.g: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_subprocess_module.php